# How do you title a letter to a family surname?

Tags: letter-writing

I am writing a letter to some family members and it is a thank you to a whole family. Would it be written as
`Dear Smiths,`?  Do I need an apostrophe, so it is `Dear Smith's`? What if it ends in an s like the surname 'Stokes'? Do you write `Dear Stokes'` or simply `Dear Stokes`, because `Dear Stokeses` seems wrong?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Apostrophes are never used for pluralization. They’re used for contractions or possession (because that started out as a contraction). I’d go with `Dear Smith family`, or, if you are only considering the options you explicitly mentioned, `Dear Smiths`.

Comment: _Keeping up with the Joneses_ is an established expression, so _Stokeses_ isn't 'wrong', but I can understand your not liking it. You might prefer _Dear Stokes family_.

Comment: The rule most (though not all) competent Anglophones hold to is 'if you pronounce the plural of _Jones_ using two syllables, indicate that using _Joneses_ in writing. but if you use one syllable (equally acceptable), use the invariant plural _Jones_. However, _Dear Stokeses_ does look rather odd (though they're probably more used to it than you are), and Orwell advises us to avoid strange expressions unless we're aiming for a comic effect (Bertie Wooster would no doubt feel totally at home with '[Dear] Stokeses all, What ho!'  I'd use Kate's suggestion.

Comment: Thank you all very much.